# SQL not saving databases

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

on cPanel, there are 2 options for viewing databases. It comes with PHPMyAdmin, and one called "MySQL Databases". Whenever I create a database (For example, WordPress, which creates a database with multiple tables), on the MySQL Databases it appears that a table was created, but it says 0.0mb. On PHPMyAdmin it says "No Databases found". Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Most webhosting companies do not allow database creation via phpmyadmin. Instead look for something in their cpanel like DB, DB wizard, MySQL users.. etc. Typically they want you to create a specific MySQL user first, and then they create the DB that only that new user can access.

Comment: @DuaneLortie It used to work, by suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: Then contact your hosts' tech support department, because none of of us could guess what their specific process is. .. Maybe they limit you to X number of DBs for example

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the solution is probably something specific to your hosting provider; you should ask them for assistance first.